# MySQL temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, temp-tables

In the project I'm working I use **php** language and **mysql** database.

The reason I thought to use **temporary tables** was right is because I perform many calculations, and in javascript they would take me a long time.

**I must show these tables at screen:**.

Table 1:

```
Total data.         |   6
Average.            |   2984-99
Sum x-Media.        |   5088.9
Sum (x-Media)^2.    |   138092659.8396
Sum (x-Media)^4.    |   1.09E+16
Maximum value.      |   9812.12
Minimum value.      |   18.23
```

Table 2:

```
Amount  |   x-Media     |   (x-Media)^2     |   (x-Media)^4
839.12  |   -2145.87    |   704122.3744     |   495788318130.694
18.23   |   18.23       |   332.3329        |   110445.15642241
9812.12 |   11957.99    |   96277698.8944   |   9.27E+15
23.93   |   5.7         |   572.6449        |   327922.18149601
863.21  |   -11094.78   |   745131.5041     |   555220958402.328
6353.33 |   6347.63     |   40364802.0889   |   1.63E+15
```

All calculations are based on the amount column, this value. I get it from the table tbl_layout_c:

```
Amount decimal (18,2)
----------
839.12
18.23
9812.12
23.93
863.21
6353.33
```

So the query is:

```
1 SELECT amount 
2 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_layout_c ) AS total_data
3 (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl_layout_c ) AS total_sum,
4 (SELECT total_sum / total_data AS average,
5 (SELECT amount - average ) AS x_media,
6 (SELECT SUM(x_media)) AS suma_x_media
7 FROM tbl_layout_c
```

**The issue is at LINE 6: (SELECT SUM(x_media)) AS suma_x_media
    because I get the same value as x_media column**. Ex:

```
Amount      |   x-Media         |   Sum x-Media.
839.12      |   -2145.87        |   -2145.87
```

**And I need:**

```
Amount      |   x-Media         |   Sum x-Media.
839.12      |   -2145.87        |   5088.9
```

I have trouble when I try to use function sum() in the temporary column (suma_x_media) of the temporary table.. It's not working, I just get the same value as x_media

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

**[Here you can see an example of the Code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16779/3/0)**

Comment: Let me know, if I need to add more information. Thanks!

Comment: What is the structure of the `tbl_layout_c`? Another is your desired output.

Comment: first column you have taken amount means you want other values based on group by amount..but next some fields are doing calculation on whole table again last 3 fields should calculate based on group by amount field...if it is true then add group by amount at the end of query...other wise elaborate what you want to get.

Comment: @ChristianMark Hello! I update the post, but you can see it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16779/3/0

Comment: please specify where you stuck!!!

Comment: @ZafarMalik Hello, thanks for replay! I need to show the "amount" column (original value) then I have to do all the calculation.

Comment: @RonakShah Hello, I do specify.. Here:
(SELECT SUM (x_media)) AS suma_x_media <---- I need to add the "x_media" column and until now I only get a clone to column "x_media"

Comment: If you show "amount" column (original value) then you should show only that amount's count against that amount what do you want to achieve whole table count (same value) against each amount..same for other fields...It will be better if you show your table data and what result you want to achieve in tabular format..so that we can understand exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @user3555852, Your question is still very confusing. please show your data and table structure

Comment: @ZafarMalik The main problem I have is that I can not make the sum of a column in this temporary table. If I do this: (SELECT SUM (x_media)) AS suma_x_media I just get a clone of the column "x_media" and I need the total amount. If I have 2|4|2 in "amount" I want to get just "8" in "suma_x_media". Please, any idea?

Comment: Can you explain what data you have and into what you want to transform them? I'm not sure if this is answer because i don't understand question http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16779/10

Comment: @user3555852, is your formula for monto - promedio =x_media is correct? reason I am saying because when I run the given sql query in SQL Fiddle the result for x_media is different from you have mentioned here in Table 2?

Comment: @RonakShah It's the same value...

Comment: @user3555852 For x-media,  only first row is same but other rows are different. i.e. in second row  sql Fiddle example, the value is -2966.76  but here you have mentioned 18.23 in Table2?

Comment: Oh, you're right! sorry.. but, this is not important. I have trouble when I try to use function sum() in the column of the temporary table... I don't get the value it's supposed to, I just get the same value as x_media column.. @RonakShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select *,sum(x_media) from (SELECT monto, #obtengo el campo monto
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_layout_c ) AS total_datos, #contar los registros
(SELECT SUM(monto) FROM tbl_layout_c ) AS suma_total, #suma total
(SELECT MAX(monto) FROM tbl_layout_c ) AS valor_maximo, #valor maximo
(SELECT MIN(monto) FROM tbl_layout_c ) AS valor_minimo, #valor minimo
(SELECT suma_total / total_datos) AS promedio, #promedio
(SELECT monto - promedio) AS x_media #media artimetica
FROM tbl_layout_c)tablealias
```

I tried in sql Fiddle with your data and It works. your sum(x_media) is 0 with data in sql Fiddle you have if you change the data same as here in TABLE 2 then you can get expected output same mentioned in Table 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! It was very helpful, You gave me an idea of ​​what I should do. Thanks for your patience and time.